# Which JAR files to add in order to get going in Spring Framework 3.0.5?

Tags: java, spring

The tutorials said I needed to import the `Spring.jar` and `commons-logging.jar` files in order to get going. They were using Spring 2.5.6.

The 3.0.5 version I'm using doesn't contain the `spring.jar` file. What is it referred to now instead?

Comment: spring-core is probably the starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much will depends on what parts of Spring you actually need. Spring contains a lot of modules in it and they are not bundled together anymore. This [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C528292745) lists all released spring artifacts. Look for ones that start with `spring-` and navigate inside to see if they are released in `3.0.5`. If they don't - you don't need them. And files named `pom.xml` inside those directories may give you an idea on what external libraries you will need.

Comment: Okay thanks very much alex. that information is extensive enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring JAR files are in the dist directory of the download. Since you're working through tutorials I wouldn't get wrapped up in the exact required JAR files; just put them all in your classpath. It's not like you're going from tutorials straight into production.

As of Spring 2.5 a lot of files were split out into their own JAR files (such as `spring-web.jar` and `spring-webmvc.jar`). I don't know that there's a mapping somewhere of old -> new JAR files so if you really want to get the exact JAR files needed with no extras you can download an old copy of Spring and look in the JAR file yourself, then find the new JAR files with those classes.

Incidentally, Spring 3.0.5 doesn't come with the required dependencies. Spring 3.0.2 was the last one to package those up... Look for the download titled "spring-framework-3.0.2.RELEASE-dependencies.zip". I'm sure someone is going to comment, "use Maven!" but not everyone uses [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) or [Ivy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy).